# How to find where user control was called from in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have WebForm1.aspx;

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl1.ascx" TagName="Deneme" TagPrefix="UserControl" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <UserControl:Deneme ID="oDeneme" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="dynamicUC" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebUserControl1.ascx;

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="WebApplication1.WebUserControl1" %>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlTest" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server">
  Hello World
    </asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

I am dynamically loading this usercontrol in code behind of aspx page;

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dynamicUC.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("~/WebUserControl1.ascx"));
        }
    }
```

How can I find loading source of user control?
I mean, when user control is loaded, I want to learn that is user control loaded from tag style (in my example; `<UserControl:Deneme ...>`
or loaded from dynamically in code-behind (in my example;  `dynamicUC.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("~/WebUserControl1.ascx"))` ).

Comment: You can add a property, from HTML markup you can set some other flag and from code-behind use some other flag. which helps you decide how the control is loaded.

Comment: At what point of time do you need to have this information?

Comment: Adding property is good point. Thanks